# Bootstrap button dropdown won't run a function onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap Button Dropdown function in order to show some warning text that a player would have to click in order to ensure that they don't click it if they don't want the effect. But the dropdown refuses to do anything of the sort.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Proton Synthesiser (15 protons)
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">
      Buying this will consume two up quarks and one down quark every second.
    </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The dropdown warning text shows perfectly, but clicking it does nothing. I'm trying to figure out where to place `onclick="buyProtonClick()` so that clicking the warning text will actually run the function. I've found nothing on the website or on this site.

Comment: And how have you tried? I don't see a click handler in your code sample. Also, `onclick` isn't the best approach to using JavaScript in your page. Create a proper `click()` function in a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0tmzje8y

```
<a class="warning" href="#">
  Buying this will consume two up quarks and one down quark every second.
</a>

<script>
$('.warning').click(function() {
    buyProtonClick();
});
</script>
```